# Why is there a .index and .timeindex file in kafka, why not just search in the .log file?

Tags: apache-kafka

I study Kafka and the material says that in addition to the .log file where there is offset, position, timestamp, message, there are .index files with offset > position mapping and timeindex with offset > timestamp mapping. And if I want to start reading from a certain offset, then first I will look for the position in the .index file

Let's say I want to read starting from offset 123, first I'll go and go through all the entries in the index file until I find offset 123, then I'll take the offset position and find it in .log? This is x2 actions. How is it better than searching in the .log file right away? It's the same with timeindex.

Comment: O(log(n)) scan is faster than O(n)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Why will the index file have O(log(n))? After all, it doesn't matter that there is more data in the .log file, the search goes by the first column (offset). And it is the same in both .log and .index files.

Comment: The files are stored by starting offset, right? So, if you're looking for offset 100k, for example, you can skip over several files, rather than linearly scanning each segment file less than that